AWS XRay unable to sending tracing data to AWS XRay console
i installed xray daemon installed in local linux machine.
created AWs acceskey and secrectkey configure my local.
created role permission AWSXrayFullAccess
using aws sdk my nodejs project
below my xray daemon configuration file
i got error in below
Failed to send telemetry 1 record(s). Re-queue records. NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors

2024-04-16T12:44:08+05:30 [Debug] Received request on HTTP Proxy server : /GetSamplingRules
2024-04-16T12:44:19+05:30 [Debug] Failed to send telemetry 1 record(s). Re-queue records. NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
2024-04-16T12:44:32+05:30 [Error] Unable to sign request: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
2024-04-16T12:45:01+05:30 [Debug] Shutdown Initiated. Current epoch in nanoseconds: 1713251701910799641
2024-04-16T12:45:01+05:30 [Info] Got shutdown signal: terminated
2024-04-16T12:45:01+05:30 [Trace] Segment batch: done!
2024-04-16T12:45:01+05:30 [Trace] Segment batch: done!
2024-04-16T12:45:01+05:30 [Trace] Segment batch: done!
2024-04-16T12:45:01+05:30 [Debug] processor: done!
2024-04-16T12:45:14+05:30 [Debug] Failed to send telemetry 2 record(s). Re-queue records. NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
2024-04-16T12:45:14+05:30 [Debug] telemetry: done!
2024-04-16T12:45:14+05:30 [Debug] Trace segment: received: 1, truncated: 0, processed: 1
2024-04-16T12:45:14+05:30 [Debug] Shutdown finished. Current epoch in nanoseconds: 1713251714294834776

if you know fix the issue please let me know
unable to send data from local machine to aws xray console

did you create your AWS creds under default profile? the AWSXrayFullAccess permission is the right one.

Yes is the default profile and attached the awsxrayfullaccess permission.  Fortunately i already fix fix this problem thanks for the comment
